# Why is my predicate being interpreted as a boolean? (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, find, predicate

I’m trying to use the find function on a list of pairs, and I want to find the first pair in which the first element equals x, so I wrote:

```
find (x == fst) list
```

Since the `fst` function lacks an argument, I thought `(x == fst)` would be a function that takes in a tuple and returns a boolean, but the compiler interprets it as a boolean, as if `fst` were a variable. Maybe `fst` is being interpreted as a function? But doesn’t that require it to be surrounded by ()?

I did solve the problem using a list comprehension instead but I’m still curious as how to one would solve it using find.

Comment: Looks like you want [function composition](https://wiki.haskell.org/Function_composition): `((x ==) . fst)`, where `(x ==)` is a [section](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator).

Comment: Indeed `fst` is a variable (even if we often call it an identifier), whose value is a function of type `(a,b)->a`. There is absolutely no difference between `fst` and `(fst)` in Haskell: both evaluate to the same function value.

Comment: If any of the answers works for you - do not forget to mark it as accepted one (checkmark to the left of answer)

Answer (score 5):

`(==)` has type `x -> x -> Bool`. In your case, type `x` is `(a, b) -> a`. This is because one of it's operands is `fst`, which has that type. Therefore, the type of `(==)` in your case is `((a, b) -> a) -> ((a, b) -> a) -> Bool`. That is, (==) is a function that compares two functions, x and fst.

What you want is to *compose* `fst` and `(==)`. For example, `(\y -> (x == fst y)`. This is a function that takes a tuple, `y`, and checks if `x` is equal to its first value.

There is a function that composes functions for you, `(.)`. It takes two functions, f(x) and g(x), and returns another function, f(g(x)). You can use this function for your program like this: `find ((x ==) . fst) list`.

Compare the following programs, the first written as a lambda function, the second with the function composition operator:

```
(\y -> (x == fst y)

-- Compared to:
       (x ==) . fst
```

Summary:

(==) is comparing two functions, x and fst, and returning a Bool.

What you want instead is a function that takes in a tuple, gets the first item from it, and compares it to x. This can be done with function composition.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass a variable into a particular position, use a lambda function:

```
(\ y -> x == fst y)
```

Otherwise the compiler has no idea exactly where you're hoping to insert a variable.

If your function calls *one function*, you can use currying to take a short cut. But for complex expressions, that doesn't work. You can't just leave off the last term in an expression and expect it to work. It only works for a *single function*.

The other alternative is to take the function `(x ==)` and the function `fst` and chain them with the `(.)` operator:

```
((x ==) . fst)
```

It's a matter of personal taste which is "better". (There is no performance difference; the only difference is what your source code looks like.)